# Проблема с ViewPager

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с ViewPager

```
 public class FragmentOne extends ContentFragment {

  private ViewPagerAdapter _adapter;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    Views.inject(this, view);
    _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
    _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
    _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    return view;
}
```

}

Ругается на `getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager()`  я понимаю, что это все из-за того, что  `extends ContentFragment`, а не `extends FragmentActivity`.  Но возможно ли как-нибудь обойти? 
`getApplicationContext()` можно заменить на `getActivity()`. Но как быть с `getSupportFragmentManager()`?
Очень нужно внутри `fragment`'a использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глянь вот этот код.

```
private class ArrayListPages extends PagerAdapter {

    /**
     * Instantiates a new new item pager adapter.
     * 
     * @param numberOfPage
     *            the number of page
     */
    public ArrayListPages(List<View> pages) {
        _pages = pages;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _pages.size();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#instantiateItem(android.view.View, int)
     */
    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) collection;

        // Add the view to the collection if we haven't up to this point
        if (null == _pages.get(position).getParent())
            pager.addView(_pages.get(position), 0);

        return _pages.get(position);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#isViewFromObject(android.view.View, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    private List<View> _pages;

}
```

Он полностью рабочий.

Как видишь не нужно использовать getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

`getApplicationContext` → `getActivity`.

`getSupportFragmentManager` → `getFragmentManager`.